# Trouble selecting correct css elements for scraping with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, css-selectors, rvest

**GOAL: I'm trying to scrape win-loss records for NBA teams from basketball-reference.com.**

More broadly, I'm trying to better understand how to correctly use CSS selector gadget to scrape specified elements from a website, but would appreciate a solution for this problem.

The url I'm using (https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2018_standings.html) has multiple tables on it, so I'm trying to use the CSS selector gadget to specify the element I want, which is the "Expanded Standings" table - about 1/3 of the way down the page.

I have read various tutorials about web scraping that involve the `rvest` and `dplyr` packages, as well as the CSS selector web browser add-in (which I have installed in Chrome, my browser of choice). That's what I'm going for.

Here is my code so far:

```
url <- "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2018_standings.html"
css <- "#expanded_standings"

url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(css) %>%
  html_table()
```

The result of this code is an error:

```
Error: html_name(x) == "table" is not TRUE
```

When I delete the last line of code, I get:

```
url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(css)

{xml_nodeset (0)}
```

It seems like there's an issue with the way I'm defining the CSS object/how I'm using the CSS selector tool. What I've been doing is clicking at the very right edge of the desired table, so that the table has a rectangle around it.

I've also tried to click a specific "cell" in the table (i.e., "65-17', which is the value in the "Overall" column for the Houston Rockets row), but that seems to highlight some, but not all of the table, and the random parts of other tables on the web page.

Can anyone provide a solution? Bonus points if you can help me understand where/why what I'm doing is incorrect.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `css <- "#confs_standings_E"`  and see if that is what you want.  I don't find that tool that helpful, inspecting works well.

Comment: That selects the first table on the page in the "Conference Standings" section. I'm trying to select a table further down the page, "Expanded Standings". Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(rvest)
library(dplR)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

url <- "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2018_standings.html"
css <- "#expanded_standings"
css <- "#all_expanded_standings"

webpage <- read_html(url)
print(webpage)
mynode <- html_nodes(webpage,css)

mystr <- toString(mynode)
mystr <- gsub("<!--","",mystr)
mystr <- gsub("-->","",mystr)

newdiv <- read_html(mystr)

newtable <- html_nodes(newdiv,"#expanded_standings")
newframe <- html_table(newtable)

print(newframe)
```

Comment: seems a bit hacky, but get that div, replace comment markers, remake html, get the table with id=#expanded_standings and create frame data.

Comment: Hacky indeed, but that got the job done. Thanks for helping me figure this out! Seems like the way the url defines the table is a bit wonky, hence this "hacky" workaround. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(rvest)
library(dplR)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

url <- "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2018_standings.html"
css <- "#expanded_standings"
css <- "#all_expanded_standings"

webpage <- read_html(url)
print(webpage)
mynode <- html_nodes(webpage,css)
#print node to console - interprets slashes
cat(toString(mynode))
```

Comment: still getting my head around this r language. - first day. That code gets the div with the table data which is in a comment block. 30 rows of data.

Comment: This is helpful, and gets me closer to the solution, but I'm not sure it's all the way there. When I define the css element with "#all_expanded_standings", it does indeed return a html node, but then when I pass that to html_table, it doesn't work (Error: html_name(x) == "table" is not TRUE). Since the #all_expanded_standings css element seems to be a table wrapper rather than an actual table, it won't pass successfully with the html_table() function.

Answer (score 0):

I tried downloading the bare url html(before javascript render). Seems strange like the table data is in a comment block. In this div -  there is the 'Expanded Standings' table.

I used python and beautifulsoup to extract the element and then remove the comment markers, resoup the string section and then parse the string into td bits. Strange like the rank is in a th element.

Comment: the div has id="all_expanded_standings" (my markup mangled by forum software)

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure I quite understand that solution. I just tried using "all_expanded_standings" as the html node but that didn't work either - still return an empty list. Thanks!